# Sqlite and Entity Framework must DIE

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

I am following this source: http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx.

I have EF 6.0.2 and System.Data.Sqlite (x86/x64) 1.0.91.3. However when I create new Entity Data Model, Generate new Db, New Connection, I don't have a Sqlite Data Source (like the link above).

Tips?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also install the "Setups for 32-bit/64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.XXX)" from
the http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki ?

Comment: I instanced for my 64-bit W7 OS the precompiled binaries but it still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Install the apropriate **32 bit** package [from their site](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), as only those add design time support. I have also overlooked this myself :) Also note: VS Express will not do the trick.

Unfortunately some problems will arise after you successfully installed it. I recommend installing System.Data.Sqlite.Core package, and using EF5, as EF6 didn't work for me